# C printf: variable string column width, left align

Tags: c, pointers, formatting

I'm trying to format printf string output:

```
printf("%*s %*s %*s %*s %*s %*s %*s %*s %*s\n", 
maxlen[0], "intf", maxlen[1], "ssid", maxlen[2], 
"bssid", maxlen[3], "vlan", maxlen[4], "STA", 
maxlen[5], "tx-pkts", maxlen[6], "rx-pkts", maxlen[7],
 "security", maxlen[8], "Capabilities");
```

where `maxlen` is an array with values 5, 13,17, 4, 3, 7, 7, 15, and 12 in this case.

However, in the output, the strings are right aligned, meaning they are floated to the right of their width-sized blocks. Output:

`intf          ssid             bssid vlan STA tx-pkts rx-pkts        security Capabilities`

Is there a way to float these strings to the left?

So instead of `[][][][][][][]security`, I want `security[][][][][][][]`for the `width==15`second-to-last block, for example.

I tried creating a `spaces`array of strings, like below:

`char **spaces = (char**)malloc(9*sizeof(char*));`

then, for each `i`,  `calloc`  `spaces[i]`, and then, instead of doing `"%*s"`, I do `%s%s`, where the second string printed is `spaces[i]`.

But even this doesn't seem to work because I would need to do

```
snprintf(spaces[i], maxlen[i]-size_of_string, "  (however many spaces)    ");
```

And I don't know how many spaces to hardcode for the third argument. There is no `" " * length` operation like in python, to create a `length` sized string of `" "` characters.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To left-align the output in the width given, add a `-` sign to the format specifier

```
printf("%-*s %-*s %-*s %-*s %-*s %-*s %-*s %-*s %-*s\n", ... );
```

The arguments supplied for `width` can be a computed `int` value. You can hard-code the width like this

```
printf("%-10s\n", "string");
```

If you don't know how much space will be taken, you can use a temporary string

```
char tempstr[100];
int len = sprintf(tempstr, "%d", value);
printf("%s%-*s\n", tempstr, 30 - len, "string");
```